# Convert JSON object to array in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift

I want to access some data from below JSON for that I need to convert JSON into an array format

```
   URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, err) in
        guard let data = data else {return}
        do {
            let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String: Any]

            if let allResult = parsedData["fps"] as? [String: Any] {
                if let allDataProviders = allResult["dataProviders"] as? [String: Any] {
                    if let allData = allDataProviders["data"] as? [String: Any] {
                        if let allFieldValues = allData["ms.vss-work-web.new-work-items-hub-default-data-provider"] as? [String: Any] {
                            if let allFieldValuesData = allFieldValues["fieldValues"] as? [Any] {
                                for data in 0..<allFieldValuesData.count {
                                    print(allFieldValuesData[data])
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch let error {
            print(error)
        }
        }.resume()
```

OUTPUT of the above code is below so from the output I wanted to get  1957, User Story and Resolved how can I get it

```
 {
data =     (
    1957,
    "User Story",
    "Design Project Dashboard",
            {
        distinctDisplayName = "Sumit Gupta <sumit.gupta@gmail.com>";
        identityRef =             {
            "_links" =                 {
                avatar =                     {
                    href = "https://orgName.visualstudio.com/_apis/GraphProfile/MemberAvatars/aad.ODJhNzk2MjgtZTNjYi03YmQxLTkyM2EtM2Q2ZDI3ZDIwNDUy";
                };
            };
            descriptor = "aad.ODJhNzk2MjgtZTNjYi03YmQxLTkyM2EtM2Q2ZDI3ZDIwNDUy";
            displayName = "Sumit Gupta";
            id = "1e741317-dc6a-41f5-b942-02dfa8a411f0";
            imageUrl = "https://orgName.visualstudio.com/_apis/GraphProfile/MemberAvatars/aad.ODJhNzk2MjgtZTNjYi03YmQxLTkyM2EtM2Q2ZDI3ZDIwNDUy";
            uniqueName = "sumit.gupta@gmail.com";
            url = "https://spsprodeus21.vssps.visualstudio.com/Acf2ada01-867f-4337-b722-208aa88fec4d/_apis/Identities/1e741317-dc6a-41f5-b942-02dfa8a411f0";
        };
    },
    Resolved,
    "VSO Client",
    "<null>",
    0,
    "/Date(1554882629083)/"
);
}
```

Comment: What did you print exactly? `.mutableContainers` isn't relevant. And what about using Codable?

Comment: Sidenote: You could avoid the Pyramid Of Doom™ by using `guard` statements.

Comment: @Larme to use codable need to declare property. So some property names are like ms.vss-work-web.new-work-items-hub-default-data-provider is it possible to declare property with the same name in swift?

Comment: That property can be used and you can use `CodingKeys` to use something shorter and more readable in your struct.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yes you are right but in json some properties names are like ms.vss-work-web.new-work-items-hub-default-data-provider so can you guide me how can i declare property name like this

Comment: That is what I was referring to. See also https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types

Comment: **Read** the output. The value for key `data` is clearly an array `(` rather than a dictionary `{`. A horrible format for that purpose by the way because the array is even heterogeneous.